# Ionic v3 with angularJS 1.x

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to use a higher version of Ionic to work with AngularJS 1.x or do I have to resort to Ionic v1?

Comment: Nope. You can't.

Comment: Its wrong pick You can't in my knowledge

Comment: anything is possible if your bold enough :))

Answer (score 1):

No you cant use Angular v1 With higher version of ionic

As Ionic is based On angular so you need to check which version of angular is needed for specific ionic version to work properly.